# Как пустить лучи во все стороны с помощью Raycast2D Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, движок

У меня есть куб, и мне просто надо сделать, что бы он пустил лучи во все стороны. Лучи в вверх, вниз, влево, право я уже сделал. А вот как пустить их под углом? Можете помочь?
[image: кубик и лучи]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _rayCount = 16;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _mask = 1 << 0; // Default layer
    [SerializeField] private float _distance = Mathf.Infinity;

    private void Start ()
    {
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = GetAroundHits2D(transform.position, _rayCount, _mask, _distance);
    }

    public RaycastHit2D[] GetAroundHits2D (Vector2 origin, int rayCount, LayerMask mask, float distance = Mathf.Infinity)
    {
        float radianDelta = Mathf.PI*2f/(float)rayCount;
        var hits = new RaycastHit2D[rayCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < rayCount; i++) 
        {
            float radian = i*radianDelta;
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(radian), Mathf.Sin(radian));
            hits[i] = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, direction, distance, mask);
        }
        return hits;
    }
}
```

Но если вам нужно пускать лучи во все стороны, скорее всего вы занимаетесь какой-то фигней. Лучше опишите проблему которую вы пытаетесь решить столь варварским способом.